# How to set html select element css height to 100% in a table cell in IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'd like to make a select (dropdown list) element fill out 100% of the table cell height. I was able to make it work in Firefox and Chrome but not on IE (Internet Explorer).

Test HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>
          Some cell content<br/>
          Some cell content<br/>
          Some cell content<br/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option>Select</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Test CSS:

```
table {width:400px;border:solid 1px #000000;border-collapse:collapse;height:100%}
table td {border:solid 1px #000000;height:100%}
select {width:100%;height:100%;}
```

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm14pzuy/5/) (works on Firefox and Chrome but not on IE)

Answer (score 2):

```css
table {width:400px;border:solid 1px #000000;border-collapse:collapse;height:100%}
table td {border:solid 1px #000000;height:100%}
select {width:100%!important;height:100%!important;}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>
          Some cell content<br/>
          Some cell content<br/>
          Some cell content<br/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option>Select</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work on IE (tested using IE11). I'd like to emphasize that on my question I've stated that this works on Firefox and Chrome. The problem is making this to work on IE.

Answer (score 0):

IE is most likely in quirks mode. Previous versions of IE didn't draw the select element themselves and thus it couldn't be styled properly (as well as some z-order quirks), so on IE < 8 you simply can't do it, unless you re-implement something like select in JS. Take a look at the developer tools (F12) to see which browser and document mode IE is in; if it says "Internet Explorer 8" for the Browser mode and not "Quirks mode" for the document mode, you should be ok :)

The following snippet works fine here (IE8β2):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            select {
                width:100%!important;
                height:100%!important;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <select>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </body>
</html
```

Hope so this might help you

Comment: I need this to be on an HTML5 doctype. I also noticed you changed the Test HTML code I've originally included in the question. I need it to work within a table cell element.

Comment: Hey  dear i have made many changes in your code  and you can use it in IE as i have already tested it, its working fine for me you can easily convert html typeto html5 doctype

Comment: Hey Moin, thanks for the effort but please read the question again. I've stated that the problem is making this to work inside a TABLE CELL (TD) using IE. If you can make this to work using the same Test HTML I've provided above, then I might consider you answer

Comment: For height:100% to work, all parent containers must be height:100%